# Is there a way how to step out form method and return page with updated element?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have couple of method in code behind on asp.net application. I would like to return messages to user in Label in case of something happen during execution and stop execution.

Code is just as sample what I'm trying to achieve.

I already tried:

```
Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
Response.Redirect("to same page");
```

Example: (I don't want to execute unzipFile method. I would like to reload current page with updated label)

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    uploadFile(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
    unzipFile(string newFile); 
}

protected void uploadFile(string newFile) {

if (newFile != null)
{
Label.Text="This is not valid file!"
    //stop processing load file with updated label
}
if (newFile.ContentType != "application/x-zip-compressed") {
Label.Text="This is not valid file!"
   //stop processing load file with updated label
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't redirect.  The postback is already to the current page and should render the current page unless anything tells is not to.  Consider a simple case:

```
protected void Page_Load(/.../)
{
    // set some values on the page
}

protected void btnClick(/.../)
{
    label1.Text = "This is a test";
}
```

With only that code in the button click handler, the current page will reload after clicking the button and the only visible change will be that text output.

Your case isn't really different.  Set the labels and don't redirect.  For example:

```
if (newFile != null)
{
    Label.Text = "This is not valid file!";
}
else if (newFile.ContentType != "application/x-zip-compressed")
{
    Label.Text = "This is not valid file!";
}
else
{
    // process the file
    Response.Redirect("SomewhereElse.aspx");
}
```

However you structure the logic, ultimately your goal is to not do any more processing once you have your error condition and just allow the event handler to complete and the page to re-render.

---

Note: I think you also meant `== null`, and you can simplify the conditions.  Consider:

```
if (newFile == null || newFile.ContentType != "application/x-zip-compressed")
{
    Label.Text = "This is not valid file!";
}
else
{
    // process the file
    Response.Redirect("SomewhereElse.aspx");
}
```

If you don't want the `else`, you can accomplish the same with a `return`:

```
if (newFile == null || newFile.ContentType != "application/x-zip-compressed")
{
    Label.Text = "This is not valid file!";
    return;
}

// process the file
Response.Redirect("SomewhereElse.aspx");
```

Comment: Yes, this is clear but I have to somehow avoid to process next method (unzipFile )after I execute first one (uploadFile). In case I stop process I will not get label with new text or it will process next method what I don't want.

Comment: @Marian: Perhaps return a response from `uploadFile`, something as simple as a `bool` to indicate success or failure, or perhaps a string indicating the error message.  In the event handler, check the response of `uploadFile` before executing `unzipFile`.

Comment: This sound as a solution for me... I did quick test and I's working. Thank you Dave